# Undefined variable error when fetching data from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I get an error when fetching data from a MySQL database using PHP.

```
Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\mbdb\Biomarkerresult1.php on line 20
 mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\mbdb\Biomarkerresult1.php on line 20
```

My dropdown list coding:

```
<select name="names" value="name">

<option value="Biomarker">Select a Biomarker</option>

<option value="Diagnostic">Diagnostic</option>

<option value="Prognsotic">Prognostic</option>

<option value="Predictive">Predictive</option>
```

Here is displaying data:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mbdb');
if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
    echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['names']))
{
    $name = $_POST['names'];
    $fetch="SELECT * FROM metabolites WHERE Biomarker_Category = '".$name."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$fetch);
}
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //-----
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is your `Biomarker_Category` correct.?

Comment: your `$result` variable is empty. check your query on phpmyadmin first.

Comment: put `while` inside `if`

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I have given my dropdown list coding above. I need to know whether my drop down values are fetched through the variable'$name'.  While running this query in phpadmin, I am getting the required output.

Comment: 1. Your post is open to SQL injection - use prepared statements and bind your variables. 2. You cannot just paste an array inside of a string - it won't magically do it for you - you have to iterate through the array and add the items one by one to your SQL query (you can use the SQL function `IN()` - make sure you bind your variables though!)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the error you see:

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\mbdb\Biomarkerresult1.php on line 20

This leads me to believe that your query is returning nothing so $result is being defined as null. To check this I would check to see if $result is null before you try the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with your code, then hopefully it will work fine.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mbdb');
if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
    echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['names']))
{
    $name = $_POST['names'];
    $fetch="SELECT * FROM metabolites WHERE Biomarker_Category = '".$name."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$fetch);//Seems to be your your posting the data, or u'r using get and post for the same form

     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         //-----
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jitendra Kumar. But i didnt get what changes i should make in my coding

Comment: You have to write While loop inside if statement.

Comment: I have edited that part. But still i am not getting the result table in the output page.

Comment: Better to debug and add comment what is the error your getting